# What influences the time an iframe is requested from browser

Tags: performance, iframe, browser, web

Can someone explain what influences the order of requests before an iframe is loaded?

My observation on one of our websites (springerprofessional.de) seems to suggest that some script files are loaded first before the iframe is requested even though they come after the  tag in the html.

"login?service=" is the iframe content in the picture below.
[image: Google Chrome timeline of elements transfered]

Comment: I suppose iframe contains its own window object, its own DOM tree etc. So browser see iframe tag, apply its src attribute and then loading/rendering of it forks to a new browser thread. Therefore and order of tags of parent html can be useless. To ensure order you can subscribe to onload event of iframe, for example and append scripts dynamicaly.

Comment: My primary goal is to get to know what elements are loaded before the iframe to create a version which loads the iframe sooner. Its not of interest to me to subscriber to any events which might be raised once the iframe is loaded. Iam looking for advice like "js of this and that type is allways loaded before any iframes", "tag A prevents the iframe from loading sooner etc.".

Comment: Got it. Not sure if order is always the same, maybe someone will post the right answer. As workaround you can set src attribute of iframe just after all your critical data is loaded.